# SPNEGO: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)

Tags: java, jboss, spnego

I am trying to use SPNEGO + JBoss 7 + Windows 2008 R2 + JDK 7, but I am getting this exception:

```
Unable to authenticate - Failure unspecified at GSS-API level
  (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
```

I created the keytab:

```
ktpass -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -crypto All -princ HTTP/win2008@TEST.COM
  -mapuser win2008 -pass *** -out krb5.keytab
```

Any ideas why I get this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: check out this url https://community.jboss.org/thread/44032?_sscc=t

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve following this url: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringJBossNegotiationInAnAllWindowsDomain

but when I executed the ktpass I included this parameters:

```
-ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -crypto All
ktpass -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -crypto All -princ  HTTP/win2008.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM -pass *** -mapuser MYDOMAIN\user_name
```

and then:

```
ktab -k krb5.keytab -n 0 -a HTTP/win2008.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM
```